# HTTP Injection Attack

Tags: http, security, object-storage

Similar to SQL injection attack, we believe that our application is prone to HTTP injection attack. We have a HTTP GET API that takes a query parameter and sends the response back making a HTTP call to the Object Store. For e.g: When consumer of our API makes below request

https://our-api.example.com?country=Italy

internally, it will make a HTTP call to

[https://our-object-store.example.com?query=select * from CustomerStore cs where cs.country like '%Italy%';](https://our-object-store.example.com?query=select%20*%20from%20CustomerStore%20cs%20where%20cs.country%20like%20%27%25Italy%25%27;)

This is the actual encoded query we use. Decoded query is added above for better clarity.

`https://our-object-store.example.com?query=select%20*%20from%20CustomerStore%20cs%20where%20cs.country%20like%20%27%25Italy%25%27%3B`

and sends the response back to consumer. In case of SQL injection, it's advised to parameterize the inputs sent and then executing it against the database. In this case, it's just a HTTP call that we send to the Object Store. How to deal with injection attacks in this case? What if some malicious user who knows the syntax of the object language query manipulates the parameter and executes dangerous queries.

Comment: Figure out what the escape mechanism is for the sql-like syntax of your object store. Make sure you use that escape mechanism *AND* url encoding.

Comment: Wait, why are you sending raw SQL queries in your URL query strings?

Comment: @user2357112 - There's a RESTful API support, but the implementation that's there for a long time is multiple queries delimited by `;`

Comment: To be more precise, this is the API we are using https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/service/18c/cxsvc/op-services-rest-connect-v1.4-queryresults-get.html

Comment: @Evert - Encoding is done already. I have decoded it for better visibility here

Comment: @Evert - Are you saying if encoding is done, then it's safe?

Comment: @Beginner, no. You need escaping for the parameters SQL and encoding for the URL. That's 2 levels of encoding.

Comment: @Evert - Can you please send the escaped version of our query? Just to confirm if it's done correctly from my side? Also, if escaping is done, then we are good?

Comment: I don't know what kind of escaping your server expects. It can be different for different SQL flavours so if I suggest the wrong syntax it could cause security issues.

Comment: You need to define a security policy that will allow or not the execution of the query. A simple policy would allow SELECT statements, but not statements altering the database state. That can be done by connecting to the database with some user, and limit the permissions granted to that user. More sophisticated policies would involve parsing the query and determining whether it's acceptable or not.

Comment: @MauricePerry - Thank you for your suggestion, but we use all CRUD statements in our queries. May be switching to the RESTFul implementation is the best solution for now.